# How to use CDK to get the IP addresses of the enis associated with a VPCE/ how to get the vpceNetworkInterfaceIds associated with a VPCE?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-cdk, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource, vpc-endpoint

**Background context / End goal:**

I am trying to use cdk to create a target group that consists of the ip addresses that are associated with a vpc endpoint (for apigateway) as per this [AWS blog.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/accessing-an-aws-api-gateway-via-static-ip-addresses-provided-by-aws-global-accelerator/)
Ideally, I would like to be able to just lookup the associated ips using just the fact that the vpce is for the service of apigateway OR potentially using the vpce id.

**Attempts**

1. I tried to use the cdk [InterfaceVpcEndpoint construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint.html#vpcendpointnetworkinterfaceids) static method using the fromInterfaceVpcEndpointAttributes (filtering by service).  It did return the desired vpce, but unfortunately it returns [in the format of IInterfaceVpcEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.IInterfaceVpcEndpoint.html) which does not have the vpceNetworkInterfaceIds attribute that the InterfaceVpcEndpoint construct has
2. I was able to use [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html#getwbrresponsewbrfielddatapath) (after consulting a stack overflow post that referenced [this example](https://github.com/taimos/cdk-constructs/blob/master/lib/serverless/internal-rest-api.ts#L117)) to look up the ip addresses for a given array of vpce network interface ids:

```
const vpceNetworkInterfaceIds = =['eniId1', 'eniId2'];
const getEniIps = new AwsCustomResource(scope, `GetEndpointIps`, {
          onUpdate: {
            service: "EC2",
            action: "describeNetworkInterfaces",
            parameters: {
               NetworkInterfaceIds: vpceNetworkInterfaceIds
              },
            physicalResourceId: PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString())
          },
          policy: AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({
            resources: AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE
          }),
        });

        const privateIpAddresses: string[] = [];
        for(let i = 0; i< vpceNetworkInterfaceIds.length; i++){
          const privateIpAddress: string = getNetworkInterfaceIpAddresses.getResponseField(`NetworkInterfaces.${i}.PrivateIpAddress`).toString();
          privateIpAddresses.push(privateIpAddress);
        }
        return privateIpAddresses;
}
```

3. I tried to make a similar sdk call ([describeVpcEndpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeVpcEndpoints-property)), but then I encountered issues retrieving the array of NetworkInterfaceIds.

```
    const getNetworkInterfaceIpAddresses = new AwsCustomResource(scope, `GetVpceNetworkInterfaceIds`, {
        onUpdate: {
          service: "EC2",
          action: "describeVpcEndpoints",
          parameters: {
             Filters: [
              { 
                Name: "service-name",
                Values: ["com.amazonaws.us-east-1.execute-api"]
              }
             ]
            },
          physicalResourceId: PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString())
        },
        policy: AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({
          resources: AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE
        }),
      });

      return getNetworkInterfaceIpAddresses.getResponseFieldReference(`VpcEndpoints.0.NetworkInterfaceIds`).toJSON();
```

I tried variations of using the [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Reference.html#towbrstringwbrlist) methods of toJson and toString but was not able to figure out how to get the array of values from this custom resource.

**Questions**

1. How can you get an array from the sdk call of a aws custom resource?
2. Is there a more straight forward way to get the vpceNetworkInterfaceIds of a given vpce?
3. Is there a more straight forward way to get the ip addresses for a given vpce?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be like, your VPCEndpoint doesn't have proper parameters.  Make sure to define what subnets to be associated with VPCEndpoint.

```
public readonly apigwEndpoint: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint;

this.apigwEndpoint = vpc.addInterfaceEndpoint('APIGWEP', {
      service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.APIGATEWAY,
      subnets: vpc.selectSubnets({
        subnetGroupName: 'private_ingress',
      }),
});
```